# Dynamic table_array value for Vlookup function

Tags: excel

Alright, I am trying to figure out if the following is possible so that I can use it in later projects. I have been testing and working on this code in a sample workbook, which is why the file name is garbage. So don't judge me.

I have a `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A6,[dfhdfh.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

This function currently works great. But I want to replace the static `table_array` value in the function to a cell reference, where I can enter a different file name at will.

Something along the lines of:

```
 =VLOOKUP(A3,CONCATENATE("[",F2,"]","Sheet1!$A:$B"),2,FALSE)
```

Where F2 contains the file name and extension `dfhdfh.xlsx`

But whenever I try to execute my `VLOOKUP` with it's nested `CONCATENATE` function, I get a `#VALUE!` error. What gives?

Comment: if your workbook `dfhdfh.xlsx` is always open, you can use `=VLOOKUP(A3,INDIRECT("["&F2&"]Sheet1!$A:$B"),2,0)`. But if your wb is closed, `INDIRECT` doesn't work. In that case you need vba

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the workaround. Would you be able to explain why the concatenate function doesn't work here though? That is what I am really getting at

Comment: At first, `CONCATENATE(A1,A2)` is the same as `A1 & A2`. At second, actually concatenation works and result of `CONCATENATE("[",F2,"]","Sheet1!$A:$B")` would be `"[dfhdfh.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B"`, but excel doesn't recognize this string as reference, so you need to use `Indirect` for this purpose: `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[",F2,"]","Sheet1!$A:$B"))` gives you correct reference and entire formula would be: `=VLOOKUP(A3,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[",F2,"]","Sheet1!$A:$B")),2,FALSE)`. But, using first point, you can make this formula shorter: `=VLOOKUP(A3,INDIRECT("["&F2&"]Sheet1!$A:$B"),2,FALSE)`

Comment: Ha, you had me at `excel doesn't recognize this string as reference`. That's what I needed to hear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Follow up from comments*

If your workbook `dfhdfh.xlsx` is always open, you can use

`=VLOOKUP(A3,INDIRECT("["&F2&"]Sheet1!$A:$B"),2,0)`.

But if your wb is closed, `INDIRECT` doesn't work. In that case you need VBA solution.

---

*About your formula:*

1) `CONCATENATE(A1,A2)` is the same as `A1 & A2`.

2) Actually concatenation works and result of `CONCATENATE("[",F2,"]","Sheet1!$A:$B")` would be `"[dfhdfh.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B"`, but excel doesn't recognize this string as reference.

So you need to use `Indirect` for this purpose:
`INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[",F2,"]","Sheet1!$A:$B"))` gives you correct reference.

Entire formula would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[",F2,"]","Sheet1!$A:$B")),2,FALSE).
```

But, using first point, you can make this formula shorter:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,INDIRECT("[" & F2 & "]Sheet1!$A:$B"),2,FALSE)
```